# Optimize histogram update

Tags: c++, optimization, signal-processing

I am updating a histogram which is represented using a simple integer array with 16 bins as below.

```
const int binSize = 4096;
int histogram[16];

unsigned short inData[1024];  // This is my input data. Short is 16 bits
for(int i = 0; i < 1024; ++i)
{
   ++histogram[inData[i] / binSize];
}
```

I run this operation very frequently , so this became a bottleneck because this loop is not parallelized by DSP as multiple bins cannot be updated at same time. How can I optimize this?

I am running this code on TI DSP C6000 series.

Comment: it is C++, i can also implement this in pure c

Comment: If you read far less often then you write, you could have an array per thread.

Comment: Sorry I meant just using C without C++

Comment: There's C, and there's C++. There's no such thing as C without C++. The outstanding question is whether you are writing in C (`.c` file) or in C++ (`.cpp` file).

Comment: @Poorna You can't specify both C++ and C in the tags. Choose one.

Comment: @ikegami We have no threads on DSP

Comment: @Inline As i am open to C solution also, i mentioned both the tags

Comment: Since you are using powers of 2, you can replace the division by bit shifts to find the correct bin.

Comment: @Poorna, I'm confused. You implied the rest of the code is parallelized.

Comment: @Beginner This optimisation is already done by compiler

Comment: @ikegami On DSP there are multiple functional units. DSP can execute multiple instructions at the same time. But since this array cannot be modified with loop unrolling because of conflicting modifications, compiler does not optimize this

Comment: Then what I said stands. You could parallelize the writing to the array by having an array for each *whatever*. This would help if you write far more often than you read.

Comment: ikegami is correct, since the histogram is much smaller than the input data, you serialize by summing up multiple histograms created by different threads.

Comment: @Beginner don't need the "created by different threads"

Comment: Even without multiple threads it helps to build several partial histograms in parallel, since that way you (mostly) get rid of the annoying conditional dependency through memory.

Answer (score 1):

To give an example of what the comments mean:

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>
using Histogram = std::array<int, 16>;

Histogram from_short(short num)
{
    Histogram result;
    result[num / 4096] = 1;
    return result;
}

Histogram add(const Histogram & lhs, const Histogram & rhs)
{
    Histogram result;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 16; ++i) { result[i] = lhs[i] + rhs[i]; }
    return result;
}

auto singles = indata | boost::adaptors::transformed(from_short);
Histogram histogram = std::reduce(begin(singles), end(singles), Histogram{}, add);
```

Another option:

```
std::sort(begin(indata), end(indata));
short * previous = begin(indata);
for (size_t i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
{
    short * current = std::lower_bound(indata, 4096 * (i + 1));
    histogram[i] = std::distance(previous, current);
    previous = current;
}
histogram[16] = std::distance(previous, end(indata));
```

Comment: @BЈовић no. The OP was finding that the data dependencies were stopping his code from being parallelised. The first solution makes sure that there are no read-after-write dependencies in the data

Comment: This is going a bit far though.. and sorting makes no sense unless you're *trying* to make it slow

Comment: These are different algorithms to calculate the same result. OP asked optimise this calculation, and I am suggesting "measure these and see if they are faster"